# How install 14.04 to virtualbox with live CD as guest on mint 17

Tags: 14.04

I have a dedicated mint 17 partition as well as VB downloaded. I also have 14.04 live CD and just need a sequence to install

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot into Mint
2. Install Virtualbox
3. Start Virtualbox and choose new
4. Select Linux, and the version of your choose the version of your choice
5. Select the amount of memory you'd like to allocate (you can use the defaults)
6. Create a hard drive of the size and type you want
7. When you boot the machine for the first time, it will ask you where
   to boot it from and you can choose the .iso file you downloaded
8. After it boots, you can install from there
9. You will want to install Guest Additions after it's set up